# Why would my Win7 laptop seem to page if it has 6GB RAM?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, google-chrome, memory

I use Uniblue and Norton 360 to check on my system and I'm not using all the RAM, but it sure seems to act that way. I have cleaned, checked, defragged, anit-virused, polished it, patted it on the head, nothing seems to improve this thing. It all started a couple of days ago. Very frustrating. Original symptoms were "Not Responding" and having to wait for a minute or so to recover. Now its 10 minutes to an hour, or it locks up completely.

- Windows 7
- Office 2010
- 6GB RAM
- 500 GB Drive (20% used)
- Chrome/IE

Comment: First red flag is Norton 360.  As a test, uninstall it and report back if the issue persists.

Comment: It's what Windows does.  (Turning off the indexing feature will help.)  And as others suggest, Norton 360 contains "optimizer" code (unrelated to its security function) that tends to pessimize operation.

Comment: Thanks to everyone. I will be doing these things and getting back to you.

Comment: I am 64bit and I have been set up this way for almost two years, but all of a sudden the system started acting this way.

Comment: It could of course be a recent Windows update.

Comment: Or it could be that your hard drive is failing and doing a lot or retries.

Answer (score 1):

Run [ProcessHacker](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/) and go to `Tools`->`Pagefiles`.

[image]

Here you see the actual and peak usage of the pagefile.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @ChristopherN.Boisjoli - get rid of Norton and Uniblue and all the other rubbish that the vendor installs too!

Check what is still running and look carefully for anything using CPU when nothing is happening or reading/writing to disk.

Use the performance monitor tool and install [Process Explorer from Sysinternals](http://www.sysinternals.com) (part of Microsoft these days) to see what is happening under the covers.

When things are stable, consider a lighter weight security tool.

Note that software is often designed to allow parts to be dumped from RAM to disk and this is normal even when plenty of RAM is available.

Also, are you using 64bit Windows? I assume you are but if not, you won't be making best use of that 6GB.

Comment: Yes, if you can figure it out Process Explorer is helpful for diagnosing such things.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only asking 'why would the OS page if I am not using all my RAM?' That is normal and it depends on what programs you are using.

Answer (score -2):

Find some uninstallers try to be their official and clean your computer from  Uniblue and Norton 360 for good. Clean temporary files after that.

Install some nice free antivirus that you can find on download.com , this is good download source.